# php on windows without WAMP/XAMPP...is this a fools folly?

Tags: php, xampp, wamp

I installed PHP and MySql separately, configured IIS and php.ini, after much research I got a working system.  I now want to get moving and need an ORM, unit test framework, etc and find that this should all be available via PEAR and that PEAR is already installed with every PHP after 4.3 but there's no go-pear.bat on my machine.  I downloaded it from pear.php.net/go-pear and got a slew of warnings and finally an error.

1. is WAMP/XAMPP "required" to use any PHP extension?
2. why does my PHP 5.3.4(from windows.php.net) come without PEAR when nearly *every* site and forum post says its should?
3. what does this errors from go-pear.bat mean? does pear require WAMP/XAMPP as it clearly isn't expecting IIS?

   We found php.exe under c:\program files\php\php.exe, it uses an unknown SAPI. PE
   AR commandline tool has not been tested with it, if you have a CLI (or CGI) php.exe available, we strongly recommand to use it.

Comment: Well, if you like to do things manually, PEAR packages can also be downloaded and extracted manually.

Comment: You might as well ask if it's better to build your own car, or just wander down to the dealership and buy a prebuilt one there. Unless there's some highly specific reason (e.g. you're making specific mods at the source level) you can't go with a prebuilt version, then go with the prebuilt version

Comment: I tend to agree with Marc B. I started out trying to roll my own, and very quickly switched to using XAMPP. (I've since switched to WAMP, but either is fine, depending on your needs.)

Comment: since you put it that way, :) I'd get the pre-built car. Honestly I just assumed, with all the macho talk about compiling php with this or that component, that this was just what had to be done.
Ok so I'm going with XAMPP as its portable and sounds Dev friendly.. but I already have MySql, PHP and FileZilla installed and running.  Am I better off just nuking them and starting from scratch?  Thanks

Comment: Got XAMPP installed and it is using my instance of MySql and FileZilla. Thanks

Comment: The only good reason I've found to building your own is to understand at a very deep level how all the moving parts fit together. A several days, lots of searching on Google and reading, a few questions asked on Stack Overflow--dodging the rest of us telling you to install XAMPP, and several pulled tufts of hair later, and you know enough to whack it all together in a few scenarios. Question is, is that a valuable use of your time? (For some, yes, for me, meh.)  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Short answer: no. Longer answer: Unless you're moderately familiar with the workings of and interrelationships between the various components, using XAMPP or WAMP make things somewhat easier.
2. I just downloaded the VC9 version of PHP 5.3.5 from windows.php.net/download/ and it had a go-pear.bat file. Not clear why you didn't get it.
3. Here is the code from go-pear.php that determines the SAPI of the php executable:

   ```
   exec($php_bin.' -v', $res);
   if(is_array($res)) {
       if( isset($res[0]) && strpos($res[0],"(cli)")) {
           return 'cli';
       }
       if( isset($res[0]) && strpos($res[0],"cgi")) {
           return 'cgi';
       } else {
           return 'unknown';
       }
   }
   ```

   Essentially `\path\to\php.exe -v` is not returning either "(cli)" or "cgi" in the first line of the result when it is executed.  Here's what mine looks like:

   ```
   J:\>php -v
   PHP 5.2.16 (cli) (built: Dec 15 2010 18:13:29)
   Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
   Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

   J:\>
   ```

   Note first that my version is a bit older. That's only because I'm testing something for 5.2 compatibility right now. 5.3 should give something similar. Note also that php is on my PATH.

Maybe PHP is not on your path? An environment variable is not set correctly? Something is preventing go-pear.php from getting a good response from the `-v` option.